# How to round it off a String after two decimal digits in this case?

Tags: java

I am using Yahoo's YQL API and fetching the global indices; the issue that I am facing is that for some of the regions I am getting values as:

```
String change_inpoints = "510.663757";

String change_inpercentage =  "+0.095152%";
```

Could you please tell me how can I round it off after two digits?

Comment: Have you tired anything to achieve this? Have you even searched this site for the answer? This question shows little to no effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DECIMALFORMAT.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "2.22234242342342";
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.00%");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(decimal.format(d));
}
```